# Geoserver 2.4.0 via the web admin interface, not adding layers in Internet Explorer, but working in Firefox

Tags: geoserver, layers, style, html, internet-explorer

For some reason I cannot seem to add layers via Internet Explorer, but I can via Firefox 23. In addition the styles that I upload also appear broken in Internet Explorer 8, but do not in Firefox. Is there any sort of modification to enable it to work in any browser?

Comment: probably this known bug - https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-4645 work round is to not use IE.

Comment: oh wow, thanks. I had actually forgot to specify that it was on a linux box.